# Angular 2+, Subscribed array of object with nested subscribes in loop forEach

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, subscribe

I have two different Observables. One, to get list of items. It returns array of objects where one of json key is "fakturaId":

```
getInvoiceForResidence() {
    return this.httpClient.get<Invoices>(
      this.url
    );
  }
```

I can use this "fakturaId" to put into second Observables and get details of particular object:

```
getInvoicePreview(fakturaId: number) {
    return this.httpClient.get<InvoicePrev>(this.url + fakturaId);
  }
```

To get all items with details I use code with nested subscribe and forEach loop:

```
getInvoices() {
    this.invoiceService.getInvoiceForResidence().subscribe(res4 => {

      // invoice list
      this.invoices = res4;

      // invoice details
      this.invoices.forEach(inv => {
        this.invoiceService.getInvoicePreview(inv.fakturaId).subscribe(res5 => {
          inv.InvoicePreview = res5;
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

"InvoicePreview" is a key of "invoices", so after that I have one array and I can simply render all items with details in HTML using *ngFor

Is there any better way to do the same but without nested subscribes? If a have many items then application works very slow.

Comment: Either use invoice or faktura....

Comment: Send an array of ids instead of looping and grab them all at once.

Comment: Lots of ways to tackle this problem.  See one solution [here](https://vocon-it.com/2018/09/04/how-to-get-rid-of-nested-subscriptions-using-rxjs-flatmap-and-switchmap/)

Comment: I use "invoice" because I prefer english in code (it's better for other developers, which will take my code in the future), but our backed developer use Polish.

Comment: That is perfect example of how NOT TO separate transport layer. If you barckend would be in chineese, you would still use it ?? Just saying.

Comment: This is a poor api design. You should be looping on the server, not the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To group many network requests together and avoid nested subscriptions (An Anti Pattern) I recommend you use `forkJoin` and `concatMap`. forkJoin allows you to group observables and `concatMap` is a flattening operator

```
// getInvoices() {
//     this.invoiceService.getInvoiceForResidence().subscribe(res4 => {

//       // invoice list
//       this.invoices = res4;

//       // invoice details
//       this.invoices.forEach(inv => {
//         this.invoiceService.getInvoicePreview(inv.fakturaId).subscribe(res5 => {
//           inv.InvoicePreview = res5;
//         });
//       });
//     });
//   }

import { of, forkJoin, Observable } from 'rxjs'; 
import { tap, concatMap } from 'rxjs/operators'

let invoices = [];

function getInvoices() {
  // Mock your invoices
  const getInvoiceForResidence = of([{fakturaId: "invoice 1"}, {fakturaId: "invoice 2"}, {fakturaId: "invoice 3"}])
  const getInvoicePreview = (id: string) => of('preview from ' + id)

  return getInvoiceForResidence.pipe(
    tap((invoices) => invoices = invoices),
    concatMap((invoices ) => {
      const networkRequestsToMake: Observable<string>[] = invoices.map(invoice => getInvoicePreview(invoice.fakturaId))
      return forkJoin(...networkRequestsToMake)
    })
  )
}

getInvoices().subscribe(signal => {
  console.log(signal)
})
```

Please copy and paste this code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-koqtab?devtoolsheight=60

Here is some info on fork join
https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html

I recommend you watch this video and read this article in full to learn how to use flattening operators.

https://medium.com/@shairez/a-super-ninja-trick-to-learn-rxjss-switchmap-mergemap-concatmap-and-exhaustmap-forever-88e178a75f1b

Please let me know if you need any more help or clarification.

Comment: Thanks! It's work perfectly. I have read (and watch) what You linked, but I'm very new with RxJS, so I need some time to analyze and understand how it's work.

Comment: I can't understand what the tap() is doing in this code. I guess that this is for debugging but could You explain it a little?

Comment: @TribusK2, We are using `tap` to take the incoming signal (our invoices) and setting the global variable called `invoices` with that data. 

This is equivalent to your code `this.invoices = res4;`

Comment: @TribusK2, feel free to mark this answer as correct if it helped! :D